# Installed MEAN on Google Compute Engine - but SSH directory is empty?

Tags: google-compute-engine, mean-stack

Where is the filesystem located for the fresh install of MEAN on Google Compute Engine?

I see the "This is the home view" in port 3000 but can't find the actual files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, SSH to your VM. There is an installation script `mean_install.sh` in the root directory.Open it :

`vi /mean_install.sh`

Here you can find all the installation paths used during MEAN deployment. At the bottom you'll see :

```
# Step 2 : Create the app in /opt and launch it
cd /opt
mean init ${APP_NAME}
cd ${APP_NAME} && npm install
bower install --allow-root --config.interactive=false
grunt > development.log 2>&1 &
```

So your files are in `/opt/your-app-name/`